# Kronecker product function definition

Tags: r, matrix, product

I have this code to define a function that works to do a kronecker product but after the is not workinig

```
kron <-  function(A,B){
nfila = nrow(A)*nrow(B)
ncolum = ncol(A)*ncol(B)
m = matrix(NA, nrow = nfila, ncol = ncolum)

for (i in 1:nfila){
  for (j in 1:ncol(A)){
    m[i,j]=(A[i,j]*B)
  }
}
   
return(m)}
```

i used this two matrix

```
A <-  matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 1), nrow = 2, ncol =  2, byrow = TRUE)
B <-  matrix(c(0, 3, 2, 1), nrow = 2, ncol =  2, byrow = TRUE)
```

to check that de process its ok it should be the running kron(A,B) must be equals to kronecker(A,B)

if `c<-kronecker(A,B)` and `m<-kron(A,B)`. Then, `C==m`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R you can do it this way:

```
library(purrr)
kron <- function(A, B){

 map(seq_len(nrow(A)), ~do.call("cbind", map(A[.x,], ~.x * B))) %>%
   do.call("rbind", .)
}
```

inner loop (map): multiply each element in row of matrix A with matrix B. At end bind columns

outer loop (map): iterate inner loop through rows of matrix A. At end bind rows

Problem with your code is that `A[i,j]*B` is matrix with same dimensions like `B` and you want to put it in signle cell `(i,j)`.

You can modify your code to something like this:

```
kron <-  function(A,B){

  m <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(A)*nrow(B), ncol = ncol(A)*ncol(B))
  
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(A))){
    cur_rows <- seq_len(nrow(B)) + (i-1)*nrow(B)
    for (j in seq_len(ncol(A)))
      m[cur_rows, seq_len(ncol(B)) + (j-1)*ncol(B)] <- A[i,j]*B
  }
  
  m
}
```